# Mojibake when reading JSON containing escaped unicode - wrongly decoded as Latin-1?

Tags: python, json, unicode, mojibake

I have a JSON file that contains `/u` escaped unicode characters, however when I read this in Python, the escaped characters are seemingly incorrectly decoded as Latin-1 rather than UTF-8. Calling `.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')` on the affected strings seems to fix this, but **why is it happening, and is there a way to specify to `json.load` that escape sequences should be read as unicode rather than Latin-1?**

JSON file `message.json`, which should contain a message composed of a "Grinning Face With Sweat" emoji:

```
{
    "message": "\u00f0\u009f\u0098\u0085"
}
```

Python:

```
>>> with open('message.json') as infile:
...     msg_json = json.load(infile)
... 
>>> msg_json
{'message': 'ð\x9f\x98\x85'}
>>> msg_json['message']
'ð\x9f\x98\x85'
>>> msg_json['message'].encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
''
```

Setting the `encoding` parameter in `open` or `json.load` doesn't seem to change anything, as the JSON file is plain ASCII, and the unicode is escaped within it.

Comment: Facebook messenger is known to produce json like this.  What you are doing is the only way to get around the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there is not the correct notation for the  emoji; it really means "ð" and three undefined codepoints, so the translation you get is correct! (The `\u...` notation is independent of encoding.)

The proper notation for , unicode U+1F605, in JavaScript is `\ud83d\ude05`. Use that in the JSON.

```js
{
    "message": "\ud83d\ude05"
}
```

If, on the other hand, your question is how you can get the correct results from the wrong data, then yes, as the comments say you may have to run through some hoops to do that.